# doubleclick studio. access parent stage. AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, double-click

Im working on a banner for google double-click studio. My parent swf loads a child swf and adds it to the stage. I need to get access to the parent swf stage from my child. How would i do that?

This is my parent code

```
import com.google.ads.studio.HtmlEnabler; 
import com.google.ads.studio.events.StudioEvent;
import com.google.ads.studio.display.StudioLoader;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.display.MovieClip;

var enabler:HtmlEnabler = HtmlEnabler.getInstance();
enabler.init(this);

var loadedHandler:Function = function(event:StudioEvent):void {
    var myLoader:StudioLoader = new StudioLoader();
    var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("child.swf");
    myLoader.load(req);
    holder.addChild(myLoader);
}
```

My child swf has a document class where i want do access the stage.
the problem is:

```
_enabler = new ProxyEnabler();
stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
```

On stage i get: #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
Anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

`this.parent.stage` should do the trick. Make sure you use it after the child has been added to the parent/stage.  Note: You could just move the `stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;` to the parent if you don't need a different setting.

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to give my own two cents on this piece. I tried the other answer but it didnt work. I got in touch with Doubleclick Support and they gave me an answer that worked out perfectly. In this example i am creating a stage mouseover and mouseout event handler.

In your example you would change

```
stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
```

to be

```
this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, isAddedToStage);
    function isAddedToStage(e){
        stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
    }
```

And here is my example with a stage mouseover and mouseout event handler.

```
this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, isAddedToStage);
function isAddedToStage(e){
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMoved);
}

function mouseMoved(evt:Event):void
{
  //custom script here
  mouseIsOver = true;
  stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMoved);
  stage.addEventListener(Event.MOUSE_LEAVE, mouseLeft);
}
function mouseLeft(evt:Event):void
{
  //custom script here
  mouseIsOver = false;
  stage.removeEventListener(Event.MOUSE_LEAVE, mouseLeft);
  stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMoved);
}
```